Looking for a film with 3 young teens/children who run away to find father but he already has a new family
So I can't really remember what the movie is exactly about, but I do recall a few scenes.
The 3 friends are 1 boy with dark hair fair skin, 1 boy with blondish hair tanned skin, and 1 girl.
I remember the movie starting off with a funeral scene, where it suddenly starts to rain and everyone opens their black umbrellas (maybe there was 1 yellow/colourful umbrella).
Then, there is also a scene of one of the boys peeing in the toilet (very unnecessary but I just remember it for some reason).
Another scene is when they are in school, where they are learning about insects or something, and the guys joke about the holes.
Then one of the guys also likes the girl and I'm pretty sure they kiss.
I'm not sure, but I think they steal money from their parents cards to run away with a train.
Then they run away to find the father but he already has a new family.
I'm not sure, but this might be a french film and it was probably made in the 2000s. I'm assuming that it's not a very popular movie.
